# Position Cascading DIVs underneath a fixed DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to create a series of cascading divs without specifiing a 'top' position . I just want them to display underneath a fixed div

My CSS looks like this

```
.fixed {
position:absolute ; 
margin:10px ;   
height:50px ;
width: 400px ;
background-color:#3640A8;
top: 30px ;     }

.AllTabs {
   display:block;
   margin:10px ;    
   height:30px ;
   width: 200px ;
   background-color:#B53133;        
}
```

My basic code is

```
<div class="Background">
 <div id="fix" class="fixed"> This is fixed </div>
 <div id="dv1" class="AllTabs"  >Underneath Fixed Div </div>
 <div id="dv2" class="AllTabs"  >Underneath Fixed Div </div>
 <div id="dv2" class="AllTabs"  >Underneath Fixed Div </div>
 <div id="dv2" class="AllTabs"  >Underneath Fixed Div </div>
</div>
```

I seem to have tried every combination of fixed,relative float positions but noting seems to get my 4 divs to just sit under the fixed div . Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Any help much appreciated

thanks Mick

Fiddle [Display Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mwl707/e267rn6q/)

Comment: I'm wondering what you're trying to achieve with this, and why the fixed div has to remain fixed. (Couldn't you 'unfix' it and let it be the `first-child`? If no why? And by the way, do you really mean "fixed"? Your css says `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

As the `fixed` is positioned absolute, it is taken out of flow making the other children act as it weren't there, hence not get pushed down as you might expect.

By giving the parent a top padding matching the `fixed`'s height and top will do the trick.

```css
.Background {
  padding-top: 80px;
  background-color:#E9BF79;
  height:90%  
}
.fixed {
  position:absolute ; 
  margin:10px ; 
  height:50px ;
  width: 400px ;
  background-color:#3640A8; 
  top: 30px ;
}
.AllTabs {
  display:block;  
  margin:10px ; 
  height:30px ;
  width: 200px ;
  background-color:#B53133;  
}
```

```html
<div class="Background">

  <div id="fix" class="fixed"> This is fixed </div>

  <div id="dv1" class="AllTabs"  >Underneath Fixed Div </div>
  <div id="dv2" class="AllTabs"  >Underneath Fixed Div </div>
  <div id="dv2" class="AllTabs"  >Underneath Fixed Div </div>
  <div id="dv2" class="AllTabs"  >Underneath Fixed Div </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect !, Thank you. I need to research 'block' in CSS

Comment: @Mick  Your're welcome, ...also check out `position: absolute` :)